# Execute visual script from command line

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code, cmd

I want to execute a bat that simply copies the text from one file to another in silent mode.

The content of the bat file is simply

```
copy C:\A.txt C:\TwinCAT\A.txt /Y
```

and the visual code to execute this bat in silent mode is

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "cmd /c Test.bat", 0, False
```

Now when I double-click the vs file it works as expected i.e. copies A.txt to B.txt. However, when I try to do the same in cmd (call wscript to execute the .vs) , although it does not come up with any errors it does not work i.e. A is not copied into B.

```
C:\Windows\System32>wscript C:\TwinCAT\Test.vbs
```

Could you advise what I am doing wrong? I know it sounds weird the workflow of this example i.e. execute from cmd a visual studio code that in turn executes a cmd command but there is a reason. Thank you in advance for your kind consideration.

Comment: I’m almost sure you have both files in the same folder. when click all relative paths point to that directory. your prompt says you are in system folder, so surely `test. vbs` tries to find `test. bat` where application was launched. try to write full path of batch file in your vbs script `(i.e c:\mypath\myfilder\test.bat`

Comment: This may be a huge shock to you, but did you not know that you can copy a file using vbs? There is insufficient information in your posted question, to explain why you've got at least one bat file, at least one vbs file, and are running one through the other from a Command Prompt window, probably in Administrator mode, _(due to your 'prompt' directory string)_. Please provide a greater understanding of the task by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62698126/edit) accordingly, thank you.

Comment: Yeap, what elzooilogico suggested did the trick, I had to specify the exact location of the bat file inside the visual script. I find it peculiar though since when I double-click the vbs it works fine. Anyway thanks a lot! Compo I do not really understand what you are expecting me to edit, I think the problem is clear. Also it would benefit me and future users I guess, if you have something to contribute rather than a general statement a problem can potentially be solved with a different method while not providing any insight of how this can be done.

Comment: My request was clear, and had nothing whatsoever to do with the simple fix offered in the comment previous to it. Using a command line in Visual Studio Code's Command Prompt window, which runs a VB script file using wscript.exe, to launch a batch file which is copying a file is absolutely ridiculous. My request was such that you could perform the task much more efficiently. I mean, instead of editing `Test.vbs` entering `wscript C:\TwinCAT\Test.vbs`, why not just enter `copy C:\A.txt C:\TwinCAT\A.txt /Y`? that would happen silently too, and you wouldn't need a batch file or vbscript to do it!

Comment: Silent I mean to avoid the command window flickering when the command is executed, which is not the case if you just type the copy command in cmd. There are numerous ways to execute a batch silently, do it from a vbs script is one of them according to https://www.raymond.cc/blog/hidden-start-runs-batch-files-silently-without-flickering-console/.

Comment: Just to clarify another thing, in the open `cmd` window, if you want true silence, redirect the output from the command to somewhere other than the console window, e.g. `Copy /Y "C:\A.txt" "C:\TwinCAT" 1>NUL 2>&1`, which outputs to the NUL device.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to avoid is opening the terminal when you do a `copy` shell command, you could use something like this:

```
{
  "key":  "alt+q",              // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {

    "text": "copy test.c test.2c\u000D"

  }
},
```

That will not open a terminal to execute.  The `\u000D` is just the return so it executes immediately.  You could make it more generic by using something like:

```
  "text": "copy '${file}' 'C:\\TwinCAT\\${fileBasename}'\u000D"
```

So now your keybinding will copy **the current file** to `C:\TwinCAT` with the same filename if you wish.

Other variables you can use: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables

This will print out the command (in an unopened terminal if you wish) so it is not "silent" in that sense.  But it is just the one line of the terminal.  Much simpler than your current workflow.